# code never terminating

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class GuessingGame
{
private int upperBound;
private int count, guess, num, pct;

public GuessingGame(int stop)
{
    upperBound = stop;
}

public void setNum(int stop)
{
    upperBound = stop;
}

public void playGame()
{
    int count = 0;
    int attempt = 1;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //upperBound = keyboard.nextInt();
     num = (int)Math.random()*upperBound;
     guess = 0;
     out.println("Enter a number between 1 and " + upperBound);
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
        count++;
        if(guess != num)
            attempt++;
    do{
        out.println("Enter a number between 1 and " + upperBound);
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
        count++;
        if(guess != num)
            attempt++;
    }while(guess != num);
     pct = (count/attempt)*100;



}

public String toString()
{
    String output="";
    output = "It took you " + count + " tries to guess " + num + "\n you guessed wrong " + pct + "% of the time";
    return output;
}
}
```

I know that it has to at some point guess has to be equal to num but the code never ends the current "game" but it seems to be infinitely looping when I use my example of 5 for the stop/upperBound

Here's my runner class as requested:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Lab10e
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    char response = ' ';

    out.print("Guessing Game - how many numbers? ");

    //read in the player value
    int stop = keyboard.nextInt();

    GuessingGame game = new GuessingGame(stop);
    game.playGame();
    out.println(game);
    out.println("would you like to play again? (y/n):: ");
    String resp =  keyboard.next();
    response = resp.charAt(0);

    do {
    out.print("Guessing Game - how many numbers? ");
    stop = keyboard.nextInt();
    game.setNum(stop);
    game.playGame();
    out.println(game);
    out.println();
    out.println("would you like to play again? (y/n):: ");
    resp =  keyboard.next();
    response = resp.charAt(0);
    //



}while(response == 'y'); 

}

}
```

Comment: How do you start your program i.e. the `main` method?

Comment: I've added my `main` method now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems here: First, your random number will always be zero. Change the line

```
num = (int)Math.random()*upperBound;
```

to

```
num = (int)(Math.random()*upperBound);
```

Your second problem is that even if you guess right on the first try, it will always ask you twice. This stems largely from the fact that you copy and pasted your guessing code. If you instead removed these lines from your code, this would not happen (NOT the ones inside the `do` loop):

```
 out.println("Enter a number between 1 and " + upperBound);
    guess = keyboard.nextInt();
    count++;
    if(guess != num)
        attempt++;
```

Further, because of the way the loop terminates, you don't need separate `count` and `attempt` variables. You can always predict what the `attempt` variable is going to be (one greater than `count`... well, actually, in your program, it would be two greater, but that's not the correct guessing percentage). You could remove the `attempt` variable entirely, and instead do

```
double countDouble = (double) count;
pct = (int) ((countDouble/(countDouble+1))*100.0);
```

Comment: I tested it locally and it generates fine... at least when `upperBound` is 100. http://pastebin.com/hhEbPC4S

Comment: Ok, now the issue is it is saying I was wrong 0% of the time when it took me 3 tries to guess a number

Comment: Oh, I know why that is, I'll fix it above - Integer division. check it out

Comment: I've got this: `pct = (int) ((doubleCount/(doubleCount+2))*100);` it doesn't seem to be calculate anything but 0.0%

Comment: and i have to use + 2 otherwise it infinitely loops

Comment: Mine doesn't. by the way this code can still generate zero, maybe the time it infinitely looped for you it generated zero?

Comment: and added in an "number out of range for anything below 1 or above the max number

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
(int)Math.random()*upperBound;
```

It's casting Math.random() to an `int`, which will always be zero because of how it is rounded. Thus num will always be equal to zero.

Comment: I had a similar situation with a previous lab and I used this: `int num;
  num = (int) (Math.random()*3);`

Comment: I saw "num = (int)Math.random()*upperBound;" in the original code he submitted.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza the `main` method is the code closer to the bottom. It's 2 separate classes

Comment: @tech_geek23: i found some other bugs in your code. please see my post below

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
(int)(Math.random()*upperBound)
```

Comment: No, you have (int)Math.random()*upperBound, as opposed to  (int) **(** Math.random()*upperBound **)**. the parentheses are important, because your statement just casts the random to an int (always 0) and the n multiplies by upperBound--still always 0. You need to group the multiplication statement so the product is cast to an int, not just the first part of it.

Answer (score 0):

From your code `out.println("Enter a number between 1 and " + upperBound);` I see you want to make `num` value in range `[1; upperBound]` but you actually make it in range `[0, upperBound-1]`.

If you want to random number from 1 to N use `(int) (Math.random()*N)+1`. Since `Math.random()` will returns value in range [0; 1) (without 1) `Math.random()*N` always will return `double` value in range `[0; N)` (without N) but since we cast it to `int` range will change to `[0; N-1]`, so to make it `[1; N]` you need to add `1` to returned value.